# cvCaptureFromCAM thread ambiguous behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

For my latest project i created a remote control app with the help of OpenCV and Kinect SDK.

It's working only if i call the cvCaptureFromCAM method from the main thread(gui thread). If i  call this method from another thread, it returns null every single time.

I've tried the common solution, to call cvCaptureFromCAM with parameter -1 or CV_CAP_ANY - it returns null also.

```
void Tracker::Start()
{
    //more code
    _beginthread(Tracker::StartCapture, 0, NULL);
}

void Tracker::StartCapture(void *dummy)
{

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

    cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAPTURE_WIDTH );
    cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAPTURE_HEIGHT);
    cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 25);

    // It takes about 2 seconds before capture can get frames from camera
    // Also we must check if the camera is connected or not
    while(capture == NULL)
    {
        if(_captureRetriesCount > 10) {
            _endthread();
            return;
        }

        Sleep(500);
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );

        _captureRetriesCount++;
    }
    //more code
```

I understand that cvCaptureFromCAM is not threadsafe. I created a mutex to lock the access, but it returns null again. I also tried to create the thread with _beginthread,_beginthreadex and CreateThread from Windows Api. Same result.

The OpenCv version is 2.1.

Calling from main thread
(http://s11.postimg.org/fges42441/working.png)

Calling from another thread
(http://s8.postimg.org/5dwd2ewhf/wrong.png)

I hope I've been clear enough, I've really looked everywhere for an answer, but I haven't come to it.

Comment: How about `CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);`? And did your camera start?

Comment: "The OpenCv version is 2.1." - oh dear. please update before doing anything else

Comment: @herohuyongtao The camera is starting but it doesn't captures anything. Check the second photo.

Comment: Side-note: please use OpenCV's new API instead.

Comment: honestly , i doubt that you need/want multithreading at all here. there must be some idle() or similar callback in your main/gui thread, do the capturing from there. trying to shift a problem with programming logic/flow into threads is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It was the old version of opencv that caused all the problems. It was the only logical explanation and i had a reason to use it, but it doesn't matter now, i'm glad that it's working. Thank you again!